# Passing Pointer Array Structure to function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I want to pass some arrays structures to a function so I can reorder by age. I am not sure how to type it.

```
   typedef structure {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    }person;

    person function ( How do I pass them? ) 
{
reordering;
}
    int main(){

    printf("How many ppl?");
     ...
    person *v[n]; ( I decided to not use dynamic allocation for simplicity of example
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    // Names and age reading using arrays
    v[i].name
    v[i].age
    }

      function ( ??? );
```

I want to reorder by age. How do I pass my arrays as a pointer to a function that will reorder by people's age ?

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

```
   void function(type* array)
   {
     // codes
   }

   void func_call()
   {
     type array_to_pass[];
     function(array_to_pass);
   }
```

This will work as the array will decay into a pointer to type.
Do note that you no longer know the size of your array. You may want to pass in the size of the array.